# Writing a route guard to wait for auth in AngularFire and Angularjs 2

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to write a router guard in Angular.js 2 (2.0.0-rc.4) (created by angular cli) that waits AngularFire (2.0.0-beta.2) to check for login status and log user in (anonymously) if user is logged in yet before allowing into the state.

My guard code is:

```
canActivate() {
    /* This part is to detect auth changes and log user in anonymously */
    this.auth
      .subscribe(auth => {
        if (!auth) {
          this.auth.login();
        }
      });

    /* This part is to listen to auth changes and IF there is an auth, resolves this guard with a true to let user in */ 
    return this.auth
      .asObservable()
      .filter(auth => {
        return auth ? true : false;
      })
      .map(x => {
        console.log("TEST 1000");
        return true;
      });
 }
```

When I run the application, even though I see `TEST 1000` console output indicating that `canActivate()` returning a `true` my route is not activated.

I wonder if there is faulty thinking in my logic, or is there any bright ideas to debug this intelligently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using this to check for auth and if user is admin:

Auth Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';


import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()

export class AuthService {


  admin$: Subject<boolean>;


  private user: any = null;


  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) {

    this.admin$ = <Subject<boolean>>new Subject();

    this.af.auth.subscribe(

      auth => {

        if(auth){

          this.user = af.database.object(`users_list/${auth.uid}`).subscribe(

            res => {

              this.user = res;

              this.admin$.next(this.user.role === 10);

              this.admin$.complete();

            },

            err => this.admin$.error(err)

          );

        }else{

          this.router.navigate(['auth']);

          this.admin$.next(false);

          this.admin$.complete();

        }

      }

    );

  }


  doLogin(credentials){

    this.admin$ = <Subject<boolean>>new Subject();

    this.af.auth.login(credentials);

  }


  admin() {

    return this.admin$;

  }

}
```

Auth Guard Service:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }


  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {


    this.authService.admin().subscribe(

      res => {

        // Navigate to the login page

        if(!res) {

          this.router.navigate(['/auth']);

        }

      },

      err => console.log(err),

      () => {

        // console.log('auth guard can activate complete')

      }

    );


    return this.authService.admin();

  }
```

Now, how this relates to your question is that without calling `complete()` on `admin$`, it won't work. The console would log `true` but the router won't navigate to the next state.

I'm pretty much still getting the hang of observables (hence there poor implementation), and if you would fix your code, I would really love to see the final result because it looks so much more cleaner and probably is a better way to do it. Cheers!

Comment: You are right! My problem was, indeed, it wasn't complete. I changed ` .asObservable()` with `take(1)` to only expect one value and complete it afterwards, and it started working!

Answer (score 2):

Can you test if this solves your problem

```
canActivate() {

    this.auth
      .subscribe(auth => {
          if (!auth) this.auth.login()
       });
    let authObs = this.auth
      .asObservable()
      .filter(auth => auth ? true : false)
      .map(x => {
          console.log("TEST 1000");
          return true;
       });

    authObs.subscribe(a => return true);
```

I think the problem is that you only create the observable and didn't actually subscribe to it. CanActivate expects a promise or bool not an observable.

Comment: Hi Filip, I tried this but unfortunately `canActivate()` is expecting type of `Observable<boolean>` or `boolean`, so your's didn't compile. `export interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean;
}` is the interface of it, according to default setup of cli, hoping it is up to date.

Comment: I was referring to the documentation on angular.io. 
export CanActivate(options : CanActivateAnnotation) : (hook: (next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) => Promise<boolean>| boolean). Your might be the latest i really don' know.